# Is there a name for the class of characters represented by [] in SQL Server?

Tags: terminology, naming-convention

I am interested in the terminology for the characters you can put around table names, column names, etc. when referencing them in a query.  A name that in Microsoft SQL Server would be for `[]`s and in MySQL would be for ``` `` ```s or possibly `""`s.

I am unable to find a generic term for them anywhere and am wondering if one exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I think" this is what you are referring to:

**Delimited Identifiers**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027(v=sql.105).aspx

**T-SQL Naming Conventions**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql

Comment: For example, if an object's (table, column, etc) delimited identifier is `"super_table"`, then the identifier body is `super_table`, and the delimiters are `"` and `"` (these are SQL standard). In SQL Server, the same object can also be identified by the delimited identifier `[super_table]` where the delimiters are `[` and `]`. In MySQL, it could also be identified by `\`super_table\``, where the delimiters are `\`` and `\``.

Answer (score 5):

The characters themselves are called delimiters. The object you are referencing is the identifier.